# Object Reference Not Set To Instance of an Object (XNA C#)

Tags: c#

I have a quick question about a piece of code that I wrote:

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
            map.Add(main.Stone);
            Vector2 vec = new Vector2(x * 16, y * 16);
            pos.Add(vec);
    }
}
```

I get an error at `pos.Add(vec);` saying that the reference is `null` even though I declared it in the line above. I am pretty new to XNA so it's probably something really simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Where is `pos` declared and initialized?

Comment: pos is null. Check using debugger.

Answer (score 1):

`pos` is null.

`vec` cannot be null as it is declared above using value type entity (integers).

Check using debugger.

Answer (score 0):

`pos` is the reference that is null, not `vec`. Where did you declare `pos`?

Comment: Perhaps the main class was passing in a null value to the method. No way to tell without seeing some more of your code.

Comment: It was being declared in my main method, then sent to this class from there via function parameters

Comment: Oh >.< I fixed it. I had List<Vector2> Pos; and it wasn't instantiated yet. All I had to do was change it to List<Vector2> Pos = new List<Vector2>();.